# Save without dialog box

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

This code converts csv to xlsx

How can i run this code without the Yes/No/Cancel dialog box. 
Want to force it to overwrite.

```
Dim CSVfolder As String, _
XlsFolder As String, _
fname As String, _
wBook As Workbook

CSVfolder = "T:\COMMON\Tool Report\DATA\"
XlsFolder = "T:\COMMON\Tool Report\DATA\AutoConvertedCSVtoXLSX\"

fname = Dir(CSVfolder & "*.csv")

Do While fname <> ""
    Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(CSVfolder & fname, Format:=6, Delimiter:=",")
    wBook.SaveAs XlsFolder & Replace(fname, ".csv", ""), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    wBook.Close True
    fname = Dir
Loop
```

Thanks

Comment: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` (I'm not sure the duplicate targets are exactly the best, but this should be what you need, please report back if it's not).

Comment: Perfect
Thank You